# Is it possible to use 8Mhz crystal instead of 4Mhz?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, crystal

Is it possible to use an 8Mhz crystal and then reduce the frequency to 4Mhz? 
I need to use three 4Mhz crystals in my circuit and I have 8Mhz crystals in stock. I looked online for 4Mhz crystal with small footprints but I could not find any. The ones with small footprints are very expensive compared to the 3225 size 8Mhz crystals that I already have.

What changes do I need to make for it work?[image]

Thank you

Comment: Sure it is possible. Your question never actually asked us how to do it though..."is it possible questions?" tend to not be very good ones. We also need your circuit. You can edit your post.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is an "Is it possible question". The chip manufacturer recommends that I use a 4Mhz crystal.

Comment: What MCU? Most (all?) modern MCUs have a PLL and can accept, not only,  wide range of oscillator frequencies but multiply them up and divide them down to synthesze most any frequency you want it to actually run off of

Comment: It should be beyond obvious that this is **utterly and entirely unanswerable without details of the part**

Comment: If your circuit requires 4mhz, you will have to divide your 8mhz by two.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the chip. You need to get it's datasheet, find the section on clocking and see what is possible.

The crystal driver in the chip will likely have a limited range of speeds and there is likely to be a limited range of settings for clock scaling. You need to find out whether the crystal driver can support and 8MHz crystal and if-so whether it can scale that to a clock speed that is acceptable for your application.